# Typo in a Proof? Proving a particular Linear Functional is Bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This passage is from a proof. They construct a functional and want to show it's not continuous on $X$.

> Enumerate a countable basis $\{x_{k}\}$. Assume they are on the unit ball in $X$. For each natural number $k$ and vector $x \in X$ define $\psi_k(x)$ to be the coefficient of $x_k$ with respect to the expansion of $x$ in the Hamel basis. Then each $\psi_k$ belongs to the set of linear functionals on $X$ and therefore the functional $\psi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>   $$ \psi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\psi_k(x) \quad \forall x\in X$$
>   is also a linear functional on $X$. **However, this linear functional is not bounded since each $x_k$ is a unit vector for which $\psi_k(x)=k$**

Is this a typo? (i.e. should this read "...for which $\psi(x_k) = k$"?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an example of not great writing rather than a strict typo.  Maybe you are meant to read it as "each $x_k$ is a unit vector such that taking $x = x_k$ yields $\psi_k(x) = k$" and it will follow that $\psi$ is unbounded. However the reasoning is really that $\psi(x_k) = k$, as you say.

Comment: As a side comment: it probably isn't worth spending lots of time ruminating on things like this when reading textbooks etc. You can see that the thing you wrote works so you understand the proof. You will often encounter imperfectly written proofs etc. and it just isn't worth spending so much time on those as to post here if you can complete the argument correctly yourself.